# How to mock a method returning IEnumerable<T> in unit test method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, .net-core, moq

I have to mock a method which returns IEnumerable as shown below.

```
public IEnumerable<Program> GetAllPrograms(string marketCode) {
            return context.Set<Program>()
                .Where(p => p.Market.Equals(marketCode)
                            && p.IsEnabled == true);
        }
```

I tried the below approach, but this call does not return any result.

```
  programRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.GetAllPrograms("ATV"))
        .Returns(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<QuoteSettings.Program>>());
```

Please let me know how to mock this instance?

**Note: I want to return data for this mock.**

Thanks

Comment: `It.IsAny<T>` is a helper method which you use to setup the mock. Just pass whatever you want returned from the method to `Returns`. If you just want an empty enumerable, try `Enumerable.Empty<T>`.

Comment: @thisextendsthat, I am unable to create variable of type IEnumerable<T> i.e. in my case IEnumerable<program> and return it. Could you please elaborate ?

Comment: Just return a `List<T>`, that's an enumerable too...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The argument to `Returns()` is the value you want the mock to return. Do not use any constructs from the mocking library in there, but just return what you want:

```
List<Program> result = new List<Program>();
// Add entries to result list here...
programRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.GetAllPrograms("ATV"))
    .Returns(result);
```

This will return whatever is in the list when `GetAllPrograms("ATV")` method is called. You would need the `It.IsAny<>` construct if you want to filter on the arguments to `GetAllPrograms()`. The following would match any station name:

```
programRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.GetAllPrograms(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .Returns(result);
```